# Windows 2008 R2: The backup operation .... has failed with following error code '2147942413' (The data is invalid.)

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm getting this error:

> The backup operation that started at '‎2010‎-‎08‎-‎25T13:01:37.646165500Z' has failed with following error code '2147942413' (The data is invalid.). Please review the event details for a solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is resolved.

When I try to backup my Windows 2008 R2 Web Server. I had identical problem some time ago (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsbackup/thread/0dbcb0d8-bf73-4cb2-b41f-f0bc8aafc4af) with my other system but solution which worked back then (disabling System State backup) is not working in this case.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Just to let you know I've removed all shadow copies and cleaned windows backup history, I've recreated Windows Backup destination drive. Nothing helped. Error is showing when creating shadow copies message is displayed.

Running vssadmin list writers command also is not returning any errors.

Checking Windows updates using SIGVERIF also returned nothing interesting (all are signed).

Trying to backup only System State also failed.

Backuping only D: drive worked.

Thank you

Comment: Run `chkdsk` yet?

Comment: I'll try to run it at night. I've runned it few minutes ago in read-only mode and nothing wrong was found.

Comment: chkdsk has found nothing wrong

Comment: It looks like this is related to creating shadow copies during backup process on drive C:. I've disabled backuping whole C drive and selected small directory not related to C:\Windows and Program files and backup still ended with error.